# Using Ansible find and file together to set permissions

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to set permissions for all "*.key" files in a single directory.  I would like to use the "find" and "files" together but can't figure out how process over the result of the find.

```
- find:
    paths: "/etc/nginx/ssl"
    patterns: "*.key"

# not sure how to do this
- files: group=ssl-cert mode=640
```

How can I get these two commands to work together?

Thanks in advance,
Travis

Following @helloV here is the final code:

```
 - name: list private key files
   find:
     paths: "/etc/nginx/ssl"
     patterns: "*.key"
   register: keys

 - name: set private key permissions
   file: path="{{item.path}}" group=ssl-cert mode=640
   with_items: "{{keys.files}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the output of find and then print it so that you know what exactly is returned by `find`. You will find there is an object `files` in the output that has information about all files. You have to loop through it and extract the `path` from each file. Untested code:

```
  tasks:
  - find:
      paths: "/etc/nginx/ssl"
      patterns: "*.key"
    register: keys
  #- debug: var=keys

  - file: path="{{item.path}}" group=ssl-cert mode=640
    with_items: keys.files
```